# Storing the output of read() from a socket in a char variable

Tags: c++, sockets, char, recv

What's the easiest way of storing the output from a read() or recv() operation from a Socket in a char variable?

I'm passing a piece of text from client to server and need to read it into a char variable which will then be displayed and used further down the application.

Comment: strcpy(fileName, dataBuffer);

....sure has been a long day, dawned on me as soon as I'd posted it!

Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading from the socket, just pass the address of your char buffer as the second argument to `read()`  (or the second argument of `recv()` or `recvfrom()` if you're using either of those instead).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
char buf[1024];
ssize_t n = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
```

Don't forget to check and interpret the return value `n`.

If you want to pass the data around, you can also use a `vector`:

```
std::vector<char> buf(1024);
ssize_t n = read(fd, buf.data(), buf.size());
```

Comment: You can use a std::string, too.